# Ruby .has_key? not seemingly working?

Tags: ruby

This is a strange problem, because I can write what looks like totally identical code in PHP that works fine, yet Ruby is failing without explanation. If someone could offer advice, I'd be really happy.

So I am iterating over a database table in Ruby. Every row has a date field. I want to generate a line graph from this table. So if there are 30 lines with "1995" in the date, I want my hash to end up with `"1995": 30` as its content. Then I can feed that data to a JS chart library.

So my code right now is

```
 db.execute("SELECT date FROM events") do |row|
      graphdata = {}
      year = row[0][0...4] # Gets first four digits of date, so 1995, 1996, 1997, etc.
      if graphdata.has_key?(year) then
           graphdata[year] += 1
      else
           graphdata[year] = 1
      end
 end
```

Pretty simple. If there's already a key for that year, increment it; if there's not, create it with an initial value of 1.

But the result I get is

```
{"1997"=>1}
{"1997"=>1}
{"1998"=>1}
{"1998"=>1}
{"1998"=>1}
{"1998"=>1}
{"1998"=>1}
{"1998"=>1}
```

I'm new to Ruby, but I can't understand why. The logic seems totally sound. I even wrote the same thing in PHP, which is working fine.

```
$results = $db->query("SELECT date from events order by date asc");
$graphdata= array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($results)) {
     $year = substr($row[0],0,4);
     if (array_key_exists($year,$graphdata)) {
        $graphdata[$year]++;
        } else {
        $graphdata[$year] = 1;
     }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place `graphdata = {}` outside the main loop. Otherwise you are re-initializing it to the empty hash on each new `row`.

Comment: Well... dammit. I can't believe I didn't realise that. Thanks, I'm embarrassed now.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you could probably just use a default value:

```
graphdata = Hash.new(0)
db.execute("SELECT date FROM events") do |row|
   year = row[0][0...4] # Gets first four digits of date, so 1995, 1996, 1997, etc.
   graphdata[year] += 1
end
```